# Mvvm-light and Common Service Locator 1.4.0

Tags: mvvm-light

There is a Compiler Error in Mvvm-Light Toolkit if you update to CommonServiceLocator v1.4.0. The Problem is that IServiceLocator is outdated i think. Will the Toolkit be Fixed? Is it outdated too? Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Please provide the Error Trace

Comment: What do you mean with Error Trace? The Error List?

Comment: Same here. As soon as I upgrade `CommonServiceLocator` package to 1.4 he complains on ambigious references and that the interface `IServiceLocator` is not compatible with the one in `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation`.

Comment: As a note, I'm getting pretty much the same issue, only in Prism.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when migrating to .NET Standard. There is a new MVVM Light for .NET Standard which removes the dependency on CommonServiceLocator. If this is your case, see this link:
[MVVM Light and CommonServiceLocator](http://www.mvvmlight.net/std10)

Comment: Nice link!!! it explain the reason as SimpleIoc stopped being compatible with the .NET Standard and also the CommonServiceLocator. If you use SimpleIoc from MvvmLight you get rid of the ServiceLocators lines of code and use the SimpleIoc.Default code lines.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you'll need to set up binding redirects for this to work.  But for now there's really no need to update service locator, as the 1.4 update is only there to support Unity5 when it's released.

https://github.com/unitycontainer/commonservicelocator/issues/9#issuecomment-331859203